# Mapview with clustered annotaion

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkannotation

I want to show group of annotation in single annotation point. That is If the mapview in full zoom out, in that state the same point has many annotation means I want to show it in single annotation and show number of annotation inside the annotation point. If I zoom in divide the annotation according to the zoom level. I struggle with this in one week still I can't found any solution.

Note:For further understanding of my question pls refer [this](https://bellycard.com/locations) link..

Please help me any idea to solve this problem or atleast give your suggestion to solve this problem.

Comment: Try this: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/qtree-objc. Excellent performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a tutorial here that does what you want.

http://robots.thoughtbot.com/how-to-handle-large-amounts-of-data-on-maps

The final project is available on github:

https://github.com/thoughtbot/TBAnnotationClustering

Comment: Thanks for your reply I'll check.

Comment: Hi I put +1 for your great link.. I'm implementing this after I complete I will accept your answer.

Comment: +1 for great link.  Anyone know of any tuts/docs to help me understand how to change the parsing in ThoughtRobot's project (above link) to work with my differently formatted CSV files?